# Extract initials from firstname and surname and compare these to separate dictionary

Tags: python

I'm new to python and need a bit help.

What I'm trying to do, is to extract initials from user input first name and surname. Then I want to compare the initials with some data in an external file. I have open the file in read-mode and imported the data into a dictionary.

```
dict1 = {'EV': ' Erik Vils', 'EVI': ' Erik Vils', 'EVIL': ' Erik Vils', 'RH': ' Rasmus Holst', 'RHO': ' Rasmus Holst', 'KA': ' Kasper Andersen'}

firstname = input('write firstname')
surname = input('write surname')

mylist=[]
mylist.append(firstname)
mylist.append(surname)

myinitals = ''.join([x[0] for x in mylist]) 
mylist=[firstname + ' ' + surname] 
mylist.append (myinitals) 

a1=mylist[0] 
b1=mylist[1] 

dict2 = {}
for item in mylist:
    x = line.split(",")
    a1 = a1.strip('') 
    b1 = b1.strip('') 
    dict2[b1]=a1 
>>> dict2 ={'EV': 'Erik Vils'}
```

From here I'm stuck. I want to generate initials which are not equal to any of the keys in dict1, in this case, the result = 'Evils': 'Erik Vils'. 
I have been trying to do a while-loop:

```
aux = dict1.keys()
while b1 in aux:
    b1=b1+surname[1:aux]
```

but this doesn't work, do any of you guys know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, I've written a similar implementation based on a list of users. You can change it to append to a list based on user input:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

names = ['Erik Vils', 'Erik Vils', 'Erik Vils', 'Erik Vils', 'Erik Vils', 'Somebody Else', 'Peter Pan', 'Peter Pan']

all_users = OrderedDict()

for entry in names:
    firstname, lastname = entry.split()
    i = 1
    while True:
        add_number=""
        if i >= len(lastname):
            add_number = i - len(lastname)
        username = firstname[0] + lastname[:i] + str(add_number)
        username = username.upper()
        if username not in all_users:
            all_users[username] = entry
            break
        i += 1

print(all_users)

# prints OrderedDict([('EV', 'Erik Vils'), ('EVI', 'Erik Vils'), ('EVIL', 'Erik Vils'), ('EVILS', 'Erik Vils'), ('EVILS1', 'Erik Vils'), ('SE', 'Somebody Else'), ('PP', 'Peter Pan'), ('PPA', 'Peter Pan')])
```

I've also used an OrderedDict to retain the order the names were inserted. However, this is not necessary.

Comment: Hi again Robert - i have have a few questions about the while True loop. Does the while-loop run the whole content in the OrderedDict() and assign a username to each name again, even though each name from the external already file already contain the usernames? 
And what excatly does the: 
if username not in all_users:
all_users[username] = entry , do?

Comment: I was going for a bullet-proof solution - Just think what would happen if you have 20 "Erik Vils". Your current solution would have gone up to "EVILS" and then it would get stuck. My solution will then continue to append a number until the username isn't in your dictionary of `all_users`. The `while True:` will keep looping until it has found a suitable username - the number addition guarantees that it will.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
dict1 = {'EV': ' Erik Vils', 'EVI': ' Erik Vils', 'EVIL': ' Erik Vils', 'RH': ' Rasmus Holst', 'RHO': ' Rasmus Holst', 'KA': ' Kasper Andersen'}

firstname = input('write firstname')
surname = input('write surname')

myinitals = firstname[0] + surname[0]

counter = 1

while myinitals in dict1:
    myinitals = firstname[0] + surname[0:counter]
    counter += 1

print(myinitals)
```

It's not as bulletproof as Roberts answer, but a bit easier to follow (hopefully).

Comment: Yeh, I append a number counter because if you have `['A B', 'A B']`, then you would end up in a never ending loop. I agree though, this is easier to follow.